# Tic tac toe on actionacript3.0 and connected by network on different pcs

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, networking, tic-tac-toe

I need to build a tic tac tore game using actionscript3.0 so i neet to connect 2 pcs by network and then send and receive data to know what the other player did.

Is that possible using actionscript 3.0? I mean sending UDP broadcast message and using a listener and TCP too.

Does anyone knows if thats is possible and the best way for me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should try [SmartFoxServer](http://smartfoxserver.com)

SmartFoxServer is a multi-platform client/server technology designed to integrate with the major online web and mobile technologies (Adobe Flash, Unity, iOS, Android, Windows Phone 8, HTML5, Windows 8) enabling developers to rapidly created multiuser experiences of all scales.

Here is the [Introduction](http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/ExamplesFlash/introduction) and [API](http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/GettingStarted/client-api-as3) for ActionScript 3
They also have some examples [here](http://smartfoxserver.com/download/get/108) and and [Tic-Tac-Toe](http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/ExamplesFlash/tris) game as example as well.

To be able to understand how to implement what you are looking for, check this documentation about [Basics of networking and communication](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b8f6c0-7ffe.html).

Comment: The problem is i dont want a server. I know that flash isnt for desktop applications but there isnt a way for me to connect other other pc in network by socket? Without internet just network and then i could just send some byte arrays with strings?

Comment: I just edited my answer with a link for the official documentation about networking communication, I believe will help you.

Comment: Hmmm so is it possible for me to use a serversocket to listen for incoming connections of a socket and then i send data between then?